# Return indices of sorted row-wise values in data frame in r

Tags: r, sorting, indexing, apply

I have a sample dataset like this:

```
set.seed(12)
df1 = data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, replace = F), ncol=5))
head(df1, n=4)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  7 18 90 30 66
2 81 63 72 70 86
3 93  8 57 74 53
4 27 82 12 56 41
```

My goal is to get indices of values sorted from largest to smallest, looking row-wise. In other words the expected output should be like this:

```
  X1  X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3  5  4  2  1
2  5  1  3  4  2
3  1  4  3  5  2
4  2  4  5  1  3
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, the resulting data frame contains indices which point out to values in original data frame from largest to smallest.

For example, looking at the first row, 3 denotes index of a column which contains the largest value in first row in df1, while 1 denotes index of a column which contains the smallest value in first row in df1.

EDIT 2: `data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, order, decreasing = TRUE)))` is the right answer as **Axeman** suggested.

Comment: Those ranking are not correct, are they? `t(apply(df1, 1, order))` should do the job..

Comment: What do you mean "looking row-wise"?

Comment: I don't see how this is ranked from largest to smalles row-wise. EDIT: It is about the indices, I get it now.

Comment: @simone See EDIT and EDIT2.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

get the decreasing order by row

```
df2 <- apply(df1, 1, order, decreasing = TRUE)
```

transpose the result to match original format

```
df2 <- t(df2)
```

the result is a matrix, lets convert it to a data frame

```
df2 <- data.frame(df2)
head(df2, n=4)
```